# What is the Samach Mem?

Tags: malach-angel

I hear Chassidic stories that the **Samach Mem** causes Jews to fight, and other evil

What is it? What is it's goal? What is it's powers? Why did G-d Almighty creat it?

Where can I read more about him?

Comment: It's called the yetzer hara

Comment: @Heshy source please (you mean: malach hamaves, soton and yeitzer hora are one and the same)

Comment: https://jtf.org/forum/index.php?topic=70861.0 https://www.dailyhalacha.com/Print.asp?P=True&ClipID=393 https://books.google.com/books?id=okgXuvcXDC4C&pg=PA96&lpg=PA96&dq=%22samech+mem%22&source=bl&ots=mbcs5cc-1O&sig=ACfU3U0XzFEEVkIafxx3OYFx-b1NXv9BrQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjQ5qGGm5zmAhXD1VkKHQM4DfE4ChDoATAFegQICRAB#v=onepage&q=%22samech%20mem%22&f=false I see also references to Samael and Eisav's angel

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samael

Comment: @hazoriz Do you understand what the abbreviation "Samach Mem" stands for? (It is the specific name of one of G-d's angels.) In that context, it's unclear exactly how much of an explanation/answer you are seeking. It sounds like you don't understand the subject of angels as taught within the Torah. Your question is essentially, 'Why did G-d establish, within His system in the creation, the quality of judgement and decay/restriction?' There are many, many sources dealing with this. But it's not something that can be distilled into a brief answer.

Comment: @YaacovDeane can you recommend a source what generalizes/simplifies it (similar to what the Rambam did to the halochos in the talmud) I am also interested in the Samach Mem influence on man

Comment: @hazoriz To my knowledge, there is nothing simple about this subject. There are plenty of books being produced today by people who represent themselves as 'kabbalists' that say all kinds of wild things. But these are not in keeping with what traditional Jewish teaching actually says. Are you in Israel or the United States or elsewhere? Depending on your location is most likely what would direct you to a potential source.

Comment: @YaacovDeane I am looking for an old source (older than 100 years) not something modern

Comment: @hazoriz A good place for you to start is the books of Rabbi Elazar of Garmizo, the Rokeach. Take a look at Sefer Sodei Razayah and also Sefer HaChochmah. That will introduce you to the concept of angels and their function according to Jewish tradition. You should also investigate the story associated with Yosef Del LaReina which deals specifically with this angel. That is only a starting place but will give you plenty of 'food for thought'.

Comment: @YaacovDeane I am interested in the samach mem specifically if Rebbe's named him I guess pleople were supposed to know who they are talking about

Comment: @hazoriz Without getting into a lot of detail, the function of this angel is connected with converting things from one state to another. This relates to the letter 'Mem' in that name. When it is 'removed' from that name the residual is the revelation of G-d's Kingship in creation. When it remains, it is like a garment. If you make the 'At-Bash' of that name and compare it to Tehillim 145:15 like is mention in Talmud, you will see the relationship. This paradigm is set up in the Akeidat Yitzchok, the story of Pinchas, Kozbi & Zimri and is part of the intention (kavanah) when reciting the Shema.

Answer (score 3):

As the comments mentioned, the 'samech mem' is the abbreviation for 'Samael' - the Yetzer Hara/Angel of Death/Archangel of Esav. You can find more written about it [here](https://www.chabad.org/kabbalah/article_cdo/aid/379349/jewish/Messengers-of-the-Righteous.htm) as the article discusses

- The angel's prosecution of Yaakov (and the Jewish nation as a whole)
- The *sa'ir l'azazel* given on Yom Kippur which goes to the angel.
- The angel's role as Esav's archangel

You can also find more sources [here](http://www.jewishencyclopedia.com/articles/13055-samael). If you were wondering, one reason why Samael is called the samech mem is due to the general [hesitancy](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/692875/jewish/What-Are-Angels.htm) in mentioning an angel's name:

> When G‑d created the angels, He instructed them to go to a person who
>   calls their name. As such, we do not want to "disturb" them
>   unnecessarily (see Taamei Hamitzvot of the Arizal, end of Parshat
>   Vayechi).